# Show phone number only on certain page

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce

I completely forgot how to do this...

I'm trying to replace the phone number on a certain page in WordPress/WooCommerce to show a different phone number only on that page.

The page ID is 5383 and I remember setting up a filter to do it, but I haven't been able to code it successfully as of yet.

Something like this, but this only works on admin backend for all pages, not just a certain page:

```
function rename_header_to_logo( $translated, $original, $domain ) {

$strings = array(
'PHONE NUMBER 1' => 'PHONE NUMBER 2',
);

if ( isset( $strings[$original] ) && is_admin() ) {
$translations = &get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
$translated = $translations->translate( $strings[$original] );
}

return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'rename_header_to_logo', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

First way to check page ID.

```
   if(is_page(5383)) { //  your id of your page

        // do stuff 

     }
```

Second way . You can use this in every template.

```
 global $post;

     if( $post->ID == 5383) { 

          // do stuff 

    }
```